# understanding spark data for MLlib data

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am reading Binary classification used in SparkML data. I read the JavaCode of Spark, I am also aware of Binary classification but I am not able to understand, how these data are generated. for example https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/data/mllib/sample_binary_classification_data.txt
this link is sample for binary_classifcation if I want to generate these type of data, how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the first column is the class label (in this case `0 / 1`), the others columns are the values of the features.

To generate the data yourself, you can use a random generator, for instance. 
But it is depend on the problem you are working on.

If you need to download datasets to apply classification algorithms you can use repositories, such as: UCI Machine Learning Repository https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/index.php